# Como validar dados recebidos e retornar erros caso necessário com API Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Bom, pessoal. Estou com uma certa dificuldade para validar e criar determinados dados no Banco de Dados recebidos via API DRF.

Seguinte, eu já tenho implementado com ModelViewSet a serialização dos dados recebidos do usuário para consultas/cadastros de novas Pessoas. Porém, dentro dessa mesma ViewSet eu estendi a função `create()` para que além de salvar no BD os dados recebidos para Pessoa, que também seja feito o `save()` da instância de User, que se trata da criação direta de um usuário para cada nova pessoa existente.

> *Talvez essa não seja a melhor forma de fazer a criação desse usuário, mas até o momento foi como consegui fazer. Aceito sugestões de mudança para essa tarefa também :)*

Então, o código:

```
class PessoaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Pessoa.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PessoaSerializer
    permissions_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

"""função para criar uma nova pessoa e novo usuário através da requisição via API"""
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        data = dict(self.request.data.lists())
        rgm = data['rgm'][0]
        email = data['email'][0]
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=rgm, email=email, password=rgm)
        user.save()
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

O problema que eu identifiquei foi que, sempre que enviado uma requisição POST e essa retorna algum erro na validação do formulário, ainda assim o usuário é criado.
Se após corrigir os dados no formulário e fizer outra requisição, o Django retorna outro erro na página por já existir usuário cadastrado com os dados passados na requisição.

[image: Erro Django]

**O que eu preciso fazer:**
Implementar essa funcionalidade no sistema de modo que se já houver um Usuário cadastrado no sistema com algum dos dados passados, seja retornado uma mensagem via API para o usuário, da mesma forma que é validado o erro na criação da Pessoa.

> Esclarecendo: Apliquei a criação desse Usuário junto á criação da Pessoa por ser uma necessidade da aplicação, pois esse cadastro de Pessoa será feito via upload de xls e não desejamos que o usuário ou qualquer administrador do sistema precise criar um usuário para tal pessoa manualmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente o que vai precisar fazer é tratar o erro para fornecer uma resposta inteligível ao usuário.

Segue um exemplo de implementação:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
from pessoa.models import Pessoa
from rest_framework import viewsets
from pessoa.serializers import PessoaSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class PessoaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PessoaSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Pessoa.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def create(self, request):
        pessoa_data = PessoaSerializer(data=request.data)
        if pessoa_data.is_valid():
            try:
                pessoa = Pessoa.objects.create(username=pessoa_data.validated_data['rgm'], email=pessoa_data.validated_data['email'], password=pessoa_data.validated_data['rgm'])
                serialized_data = PessoaSerializer(instance=pessoa)
                return Response(serialized_data.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except IntegrityError:
                content = {'erro': 'Já existe uma pessoa com esse username em nossos registros'}
                return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(pessoa_data._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Vai ser basicamente este fluxo que deve seguir. Em caso de dúvida consulte a [documentação](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling).

Comment: Obrigado, viu. Ajudou bastante e compreendi exatamente o que precisava ser feito! :)